# Google Places Autocomplete API does not return city and state when the address is selected

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to get my search_bar to populate with the whole address (street name and number, city, state).. right now only the street name and number populate in the search bar after the address is selected.

```
   [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Createbusinessaccount : ContentPage
{

    string GooglePlacesApiKey = "I removed this";  // Replace this with your api key

    public Createbusinessaccount ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        search_bar.ApiKey = GooglePlacesApiKey;
        search_bar.Type = PlaceType.Address;
        search_bar.Components = new Components("country:us"); // Restrict results to Australia and New Zealand
        search_bar.PlacesRetrieved += Search_Bar_PlacesRetrieved;
        search_bar.TextChanged += Search_Bar_TextChanged;
        search_bar.MinimumSearchText = 2;
        results_list.ItemSelected += Results_List_ItemSelected;

    }



    void Search_Bar_PlacesRetrieved(object sender, AutoCompleteResult result)
    {
        results_list.ItemsSource = result.AutoCompletePlaces;
        spinner.IsRunning = false;
        spinner.IsVisible = false;

        if (result.AutoCompletePlaces != null && result.AutoCompletePlaces.Count > 0)
            results_list.IsVisible = true;
    }

    void Search_Bar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
        {
            results_list.IsVisible = false;
            spinner.IsVisible = true;
            spinner.IsRunning = true;
        }
        else
        {
            results_list.IsVisible = true;
            spinner.IsRunning = false;
            spinner.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }

    async void Results_List_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        var prediction = (AutoCompletePrediction)e.SelectedItem;



        results_list.SelectedItem = null;

        var place = await Places.GetPlace(prediction.Place_ID, GooglePlacesApiKey);

        search_bar.Text = place.Name;

        if (place != null)
            await DisplayAlert(
                place.Name, string.Format("Lat: {0}\nLon: {1}", place.Latitude, place.Longitude), "OK");



    }
```

Comment: is the problem that Places isn't returning the data you need, or is it that you don't know how to assign the results to the search bar?

Comment: It returns an autocomplete address when the user searches

Comment: My problem is that when the user selects an address from the list.  The search bar text is only populated with the street name and number,  but no city and state.  And I dont know how to get that information from the list into the search bar

Comment: search_bar.Text = place.Name + " " + place.City + " " + place.State; (I don't know exactly what the properties of the place object look like, you will need to look them up)